# GraphQL client library for Python

Tags: open-source, python, library, graphql

I am searching for a GraphQL client library for Python.

Required features:

- GraphQL client library
- open-source
- for Python

Answer (score 1):

#### [GQL: Python GraphQL Client Library](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql-next)

GQL is a GraphQL Client Python library intended to help Python application make GraphQL API call while enjoying the advantages that come with GraphQL.

- Strongly-Typed response objects (dynamically created in build time to match your query)
- Query Validation that checks your code's queries against the GraphQL server's schema.

#### [py-graphql-client 0.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/py-graphql-client/)